# Capybara slow test, view rendering takes a lot of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara, capybara-webkit, poltergeist

The issue persist on Rails 4.2 with the newest capybara.

I think it is not a driver specific issue, because it slow with rack_test, capybara-webkit and even poltgeist.

Rendering takes approx. 78086ms.

Example log output:

```
   (6.5ms)  COMMIT
Started GET "/coming-soon" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-07 11:53:27 +0200
Processing by FeaturesController#index as HTML
  TranslationKey Load (10.0ms)  SELECT  "translation_keys".* FROM "translation_keys" WHERE "translation_keys"."key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["key", "features.page-description"]]
  Feature Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "features".* FROM "features"
  TranslationKey Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "translation_keys".* FROM "translation_keys" WHERE "translation_keys"."key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["key", "features.see_preview"]]
  TranslationKey Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "translation_keys".* FROM "translation_keys" WHERE "translation_keys"."key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["key", "features.form-description"]]
  Rendered features/index.html.haml within layouts/application (67.2ms)
  TranslationKey Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "translation_keys".* FROM "translation_keys" WHERE "translation_keys"."key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["key", "meta.title"]]
  TranslationKey Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "translation_keys".* FROM "translation_keys" WHERE "translation_keys"."key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["key", "meta.description"]]
  TranslationKey Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "translation_keys".* FROM "translation_keys" WHERE "translation_keys"."key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["key", "meta.keywords"]]
  MenuItem Load (6.1ms)  SELECT "menu_items".* FROM "menu_items" WHERE "menu_items"."menu_category" = $1  ORDER BY position ASC  [["menu_category", "3"]]
  TranslationKey Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "translation_keys".* FROM "translation_keys" WHERE "translation_keys"."key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["key", "page.instagram_url"]]
  TranslationKey Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "translation_keys".* FROM "translation_keys" WHERE "translation_keys"."key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["key", "page.pinterest_url"]]
  Rendered shared/_header.html.haml (416.5ms)
  MenuItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "menu_items".* FROM "menu_items" WHERE "menu_items"."menu_category" = $1  ORDER BY position ASC  [["menu_category", "1"]]
  Rendered shared/_flash_messages.html.haml (5.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_analytics.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 78086ms (Views: 78046.3ms | ActiveRecord: 21.5ms)
```

TransitionKeys are fast_gettext's stuff. 
MenuItems is a cell (cells gem).

I use the following gems for testing:

```
group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem "minitest-rails-capybara"
  gem 'capybara-email'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
end
```

I also tried changing transaction and truncation strategies.

What's wrong?

**EDIT:**

when I start a local server with:
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails c
it is painfully slow even if config.assets.debug = false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this only happens for the first test that is run then this has nothing to do with Capybara and is most likely the asset pipeline compiling the assets.  You can try precompiling them in the test environment before running the test and see if that speeds it up.

Comment: commenting out application.css in test env helped

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `config.assets.debug = false` is set in your relevant `config/environments/*.rb` files (perhaps just `test.rb`).

Comment: This was the only solution that helped me... 5 years later ;-)